# how to create a node slideshow with customized fields?

Tags: javascript, views

[image: slideshow]I have created a view displaying an image with two other fields, i have created a lightbox slideshow of that image, now i want that the slide show should display other required fields of the content type along with the image. How to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the details like the modules you've used for slideshow?

Comment: I have used lightbox module

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

**steps :**

> Enable view slideshow module.
>
> Create a view using existing content type(ex-product).
>
> View format: Slideshow
>
> Add item for slideshow (such as the title, image etc).

Or you can use [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module.

Comment: i have tried that, but that is not the way i wanted, 
1st requirement: grid of images with two other fields
2nd requirement: slide show with other fields along with the existing fields

Comment: may u pls attach the screenshots so its better to understand.